# Eclipse loses my "Show line numbers" preference setting

Tags: eclipse, settings, preferences

I'm using Eclipse version:

```
Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)   
Build id: 20180405-1200
```

After checking "Show line numbers"
   in  Windows -> Preferences - General - Editors - Text Editors
line numbers appear in editor
However, after closing Eclipse and re-opening the same workspace, this settings is lost. No line numbers are shown, and "Show line numbers" is not checked.
For some reason my eclipse is not saving this settings.

I assume it's a bug but i was looking for some workaround.
I tried adding to the project's org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs file the following line:

```
lineNumberRuler=true
```

but that did not fix the problem. Once Eclipse starts with that workspace, the above line is changed to lineNumberRuler=false. When I set it again it is erased from the file.

The above file, in my workspace contains the following:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
overviewRuler_migration=migrated_3.1
spacesForTabs=true
```

I don't know what's the meaning of the overviewRuler_migration property, but deleting it from the file and restarting eclipse did not help.

Is there any way to get the Save line number setting to not be lost after each close-reopen of the workspace? i don't want to revert to an older release of eclipse, and i don't want to install a newer version of eclipse unless this has been fixed in it, if it's indeed a bug.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what caused my problem, but comparing it to another workspace that was working ok, i noticed the workspace i described above had a folder called ".recommenders". I don't know how it got created or what it's purpose is but deleting it solved my problem and i haven't noticed anything i need missing

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try with a brand new workspace, or with other workspaces? Does the problem exist for these too, or is it limited to just this one?
2. It's possible that the Eclipse Preference Recorder is restoring the setting. Follow these steps to turn it off:

a) Go go Preferences > Oomph > Setup Tasks > Preference Recorder and turn it off.

b) Set the line ruler preference to the desired value and shut down Eclipse.

c) Rename/delete the folders named *oomph* under your [user_home]/.eclipse folder.

d) Start Eclipse.
If this works, it would mean that the preference was being restored by the preference recorder - you may have had it on in the past and turned it off later but the older prefs are still being restored, etc.

Hope this helps.